# List Row smooth animation

Tags: animation, swiftui

I have a list that I would like to make a `view` appear. The following code produces a jerky `animation` when I tap the row. I would like to modify to create a more smooth animation. Is there a way to smoothly animate changes to a `List`?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<10){index in
             ListItem(title: index)
        }
    }
}

struct ListItem: View {
    @State var title: Int
    @State var bOpen = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("\(title+2) items")
            withAnimation{
                self.bOpen ? Options() : nil
            }
        }.onTapGesture {
            self.bOpen.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct Options: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName:"circle.fill")
            Image(systemName:"star")
        }

    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.animation()` modifier on the `ListItem`

like:

```
ListItem(title: index).animation(.default)
```

You can also apply it on the `VStack` itself (if you managed to **not** animate all `ListItem` changes).

And no need for `withAnimation`

Answer (score 0):

If you have no other items, the other answer with listItem is good enough.

But specifically, you have some other animated items in the listItem, you may do the following:

```
 var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Text("\(title+2) items")
        self.bOpen ? Options().transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .top)) : nil
    }.onTapGesture {
    withAnimation{
    self.bOpen.toggle()}
    }
}
```

1. correct the position where to place "withAnimation"
2. introduce a peaceful `transtion` action.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Still doesn’t achieve the effect that I want. The animation appears jerky. The appearance and disappearance of the view is abrupt. Was going for something similar to what’s in the app Overcast when you are viewing an episode.